# How to inject specific implementation of interface?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

In spring (boot) I have multiple implementations of an interface. When injecting the interface I would like to define which specific implementation I want to be injected.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `@Resource` and `@Qualifier`: 
(All code is kotlin for simplicity)

0) Interface definition:

```
interface Counter
class MemoryCounter : Counter
class DatabaseCounter : Counter
```

1) Mark you implementations with a name:

```
@Resource("myMemoryCounter")
@Component
class MemoryCounter : Counter

@Resource("myDatabaseCounter")
@Component
class DatabaseCounter : Counter
```

2) Inject the desired implemention in your Service

```
@Service
class Service(
    @Qualifier("myMemoryCounter") val counter1: Counter, // will be MemoryCounter 
    @Qualifier("myDatabaseCounter") val counter2: Counter, // will be DatbaseCounter 
)
```

Comment: You ask for java, and you instantanely answer yourself in kotlin?

Comment: Never asked for java, I asked for spring. I am using kotlin im my project. I just found it works that way and document it for me and maybe others here on SO.

Comment: As for today, unless specified everybody will assume java unless kotlyn is explicitely specified...